# Prevent NSTextField from being left blank

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I have a NSTextField with an NSNumberFormatter inside of it.  I've seen textfields that if you leave them blank it just puts whatever number was in it previously back into it.  I'm curious if there's a setting in Interface Builder that provides this behavior.  I can't seem to find it, but I'm fairly new to IB and might not be looking in the right spot.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no behaviour that I know of in IB other than the default value (which won't help here), but you could use **NSTextFieldDelegate** (extension of NSControlTextEditingDelegate) to monitor when editing finishes, using **control:textShouldEndEditing:** you can throw a value back into the box if it's left blank.  You can [read about NSTextFieldDelegate here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Ya I guess delegate is the easiest way to do it if it's not a built in feature.  I'm using Mac OS, not touch so I think NSTextFieldDelegate is what I want.  Thanks

Comment: yeah, sorry about that.  I'm so used to writing stuff for iPhone, it becomes automatic!  Post edited accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave just back some default value for case the user deleted the input

1) Subclass NSNumberFormatter

2) Implement (will put a 0, if empty)

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj {

    if (obj == nil) {
        return @"0";
    }

    return [super stringForObjectValue:obj];

}
```

3) set the class in IB